# How to add table rows from another table in html

Tags: html

I have several HTML pages that have single row tables with information I would like to collate into a single summary table in a new HTML file. Each single row table lives in its own HTML file and looks something like this.

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th>Heading2</th>
        <th>Heading3</th>
    </tr>

<div id="Row1_to_include">
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>    
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value3</td>    
    </tr> </div>
```

I've tried an iframe statement like the one below for the summary file, but it does not work. What are my options to make this work?  Platform is html on apache server.

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th>Heading2</th>
        <th>Heading3</th>
    </tr>

<iframe> src="file1.html#Row1_to_include" </iframe>
<iframe> src="file2.html#Row2_to_include" </iframe>
<iframe> src="file3.html#Row3_to_include" </iframe>

</table>
```

Comment: You are aware that HTML is a markup language, *not* a programming language? The question is, where is your data coming from? Can you not just create the desired table by hand, done?

Comment: This is a team collaboration page summary.  There will be many individual html files that each member of the team will update.  Of course the summary page can be created manually, but I'm hoping there's an easier way to include all the table entries from the other existing tables without having to rewrite it all from scratch.

Comment: A more common approach would be to have everyone enter their data into a database, then use PHP/mySQL to generate the summary page by fetching the required data from the database. If that is not a possibility at all, you could still work with a script (PHP, Python, whatever) that actually reads the team member's HTML files and parses them in a way that strips out the relevant data, then generates the summary page from that.

Comment: Or... just use one of the many existing team collaboration tools out there.